# Showing PDF bytestream in the response in a new browser window

Tags: javascript, html, spring-mvc, pdf

I am trying to popup a PDF file's byte stream in a new Window using Javascript.

In the backend I am using a Spring Controller code as given below

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/print", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json")
public ModelAndView printCompareChart(@RequestBody ChartGenerationRequest request,
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest ) throws Exception {

   byte [] bytes =//bytestream of a pdf file
   ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
   mav.addObject("byteArray", bytes);
   mav.setViewName("pdfByteArrayPrint");
   return mav;
 }
```

This post method is called by an AJAX call from the JS like this

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    cache: false,
    type:'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType:"application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    success: function (responseData){
        var win=window.open('about:blank', target, windowProperties);
        with(win.document)
        {
          open();
          write(responseData);
          close();
        }
    }
});
```

From the chrome developer tools I can see that the response data is coming up as bytes, but on the new browser window it doesn't show the actual pdf file, but the bytes itself.

This is the output I am getting

[image: output window]
How can I show the actual file here, extracted from the byte stream?

Comment: I am sending in json data and getting back pdf as stream

Comment: `win.document` is an HTML document. It doesn't matter what you write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not get this working at all. So I came up with an alternative to this. From the JS side I created a hidden form and submitted with data, the backend responded back with the pdf bytestream, which was then displayed on the new browser window. I had to sacrifice the automatic json conversion to java object in this case, and handle each parameters individually from the httpRequest passed.

**JS Code**

```
openWithPost = function(url, title, data, target) {

  var form = document.createElement("form");
  form.action = url;
  form.method = "POST";
  form.target = target || "_self";
  if (data) {
    for ( var key in data) {
        var input = document.createElement('input');
        input.type = 'hidden';
        input.name = key;
        input.value = data[key];
        form.appendChild(input);
    }
  }
  form.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(form);
  form.submit();
}
```

**Backend Spring code**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/printCompareChart", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView printCompareChart(HttpServletRequest httpRequest)
{
   //get each parameter from httpRequest and handle it
   String fileName = httpRequest.getParameter("fileName");
   //logic to create the pdf file
   byte[] bytes = //get bytes of the pdf file
   ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
   mav.addObject("byteArray", bytes);
   mav.setViewName("pdfByteArrayPrint");
   return mav;
}
```