# How to display pdf from byte[] stream in browser?

Tags: java, servlets, pdf, response, bytestream

I am using a servlet and passing the http response with the `byte[]` stream to the browser. I have set `response.setContentType("application/pdf");` in my java code but it still display garbage code like : `JVBERi0xLjQKJeLjz9MKNCAwIG9iago8PC9UeXBlL1hPYmplY3QvQ29sb3JTcGFjZS9EZXZpY2VSR0IvU3VidHlwZS9JbWFnZS9CaXR`

What should I do to correctly view the pdf into the browser ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Showing PDF bytestream in the response in a new browser window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25762363/showing-pdf-bytestream-in-the-response-in-a-new-browser-window)

Comment: The "garbage" you're getting looks like a base64-encoded PDF header.

Comment: The suggested duplicate seems to be a problem with content type headers, but this looks more like a base64 encoding issue, while the contentType part is actually handled properly, as the OP suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDF documents can easily be recgnozied because their first characters are %PDF followed by a version number.

You can see here that the displayed content does not follow that rule, so that is no PDF. Still, this String looks a lot like Base 64 encoded content, and indeed, if you are to try a base64 decoder, you'll see that the decoded output prints a doc that starts with :

```
%PDF-1.4
... some binary stuff
```

Therefore, what seems to be missing is the decoding of the content, prior to sending it through the response. 
To perform this decoding, Apache Commons Codec has a flexible implementation of Base64 encoding and decoding, but you can also use various classes and utils to do the job. See the answers on this SO thread :

[Decode Base64 data in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469695/decode-base64-data-in-java)